# Jupyter notebooks automatically opens three brackets/parenthesis instead of two. How to disable this?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I recently installed anaconda and am using jupyter notebooks to code. When opening a bracket - "(" in the editor, it automatically opens three like this - ((). Same with parenthesis. How can this be corrected/ disabled?

`print((""text")`

Comment: Are you using JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook? You added tags for both so it is not clear; the configuration change needed in both is similar but slightly different.

Comment: Actually this sounds like a bug. which version of Notebook/JupyterLab are you using? It is not like that for me on the recent versions.

Comment: Hi, both JupyterLab 3.0.14 and Jupyter Notebook 6.3.0 gives me this error.

Comment: I reinstalled anaconda and tried older versions of Jupyter Notebook and JupyterLab, but they too have the same bug.

Comment: Maybe it is browser-specific? What browser are you using? The most recent JupyterLab is 3.0.16 by the way.

Comment: Oh you are right! I opened Jupyter Notebook using Windows Edge and the bug isnt there. So it appears to be an issure with the Chrome browser.

Comment: So I found the issue. I was using a 3rd party keyboard app that lets me switch between English and my local language on Chrome. I disabled the extension and the issue solved itself. Many thanks for your help! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved -- I was using a 3rd party keyboard app that lets me switch between English and my local language on Chrome. I disabled the extension and the issue solved itself.